# Output is 23.Please explain

Tags: java, operators, post-increment, pre-increment

This is my code snippet.

```
class Example{
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a=10;
int x;
 x= ++a + ++a;
System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Output is **23**. Need little help.

Comment: 11 + 12 = 23...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide `x= ++a + ++a;` into 3 pieces.

Firstly, the first `++a` will be done. Then the second `++a` will be done. Then the `+` will be done.

So after the first `++a`, `a` will be `11`. After the second `++a`, `a` will be `12`. After the `+`, `a` will be `11 + 12 = 23`.